# Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.CampaignGroupTaxonomyManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8.2

Recently split the configs for sitecore 8.2 CD environment but its throwing exception on as per below,

```
6956 15:13:34 WARN  Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.CampaignGroupTaxonomyManager. The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class. Parameter info: Count: 4. Parameter types: Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.Data.ItemDb.ItemTaxonomyRepository, Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.Mapping.TaxonomyTypeMapper, System.String, Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.TaxonomyCache

6956 15:13:34 ERROR Error loading hook: <hook type="Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.Hooks.Initializer, Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy" patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.MarketingTaxonomy.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException
Message: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.CampaignGroupTaxonomyManager. No matching constructor was found.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject[T](XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.TaxonomyManagerProvider..ctor()
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.Hooks.Initializer.Initialize()
   at Sitecore.Events.Hooks.HookManager.LoadAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the issue by deleting Sitecore.Analytics.MarketingTaxonomy.config as 8.2 have renamed config

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no `Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.dll` in your `bin folder.

Double check if it's there and if not, copy it from Sitecore zip.